# Silverlight: How Assembly version affects ApplicationSettengs

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage, application-settings

I am looking for information how IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings are affected by Assembly Version. Is there a way to specify version to get same ApplicationSettings for any version of same app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft, the ApplicationSettings are per xap path, not assembly version:

> Their scope is determined by the full path of the application .xap file

Checkout this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221360%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) article for more info.

Sounds like support for multiple browsers is known to be flaky.

You will also find that running your app in the Visual Studio dev server will have unexpected results if/when the port changes.